# Can database fields be dragged and dropped (as textboxes, not a gridview) into an ASP.Net form?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, t4, llblgenpro

In VisualStudio, when you drag and drop a table or an individual column from a data connection in server explorer, a gridview is created.

What I want to be able to do is drag and drop the columns to make a quick and dirty detail form to display an individual record.  Is this possible in any way?

An even better way to do this would be via a custom T4 or LLBLGen template but I have no clue how to do this.

Any other suggested approaches?

UPDATE:  A DetailsView is the *type* of thing I am looking for, in that you can select a data source and the specific columns you want, but I'd like to be able to have manual control of the layout and formatting after the initial drag and drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be literally no way to do this in VS that I have come across.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest binding a DetailsView to the table using a data source (SqlDataSource) instead. You might find [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/#master), especially [this one](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-10-vb.aspx) helpful.

In response to your update, have a look at the [FormView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/formview.aspx) control. It gives you complete control of the layout using templated sections.